# How to delete all the files marked as not added to git in a folder? (many deleted files reappear after switching branches)

Tags: git, intellij-idea

This question says that when you change branches git does not remove existing files, it just adds or updates them as per the overlay mode

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556730/1058292

If I switch to an old branch and back many files reappear that were once deleted (directories too).  My solution is split into the following structure

Solution
___Project1
_____CoreFiles
_____BuildFiles
___Project2
_____CoreFiles
_____BuildFiles

So I just want to delete those files in my CoreFiles directories that are not added to git.  I have about 8 project directories and I don't want to delete the build contents.  Possibly by deleting those files that are marked as not added in git (red in intellij).  Is this possible?

Comment: `git clean -xdf` removes everything which is not tracked. It's dangerous operation, do on your own risk. Ah, if they are marked as deleted, than you need to `git reset --hard HEAD~0`. But in the future, use `git worktree ...`

Comment: Yes, I'd rather delete only the corefiles and keep my build files (I just switch branches quickly every now and then).  `git clean -xdf` will delete my core files and `git worktree` won't preserve them but yes, moving over to a worktree directory is probably better than switching my working branch. thanks, if there is an option that can just delete inside a directory and the subdirectories of it, files that are not in git, that would do the job

Comment: `git clean` documentation: *If any optional <path>... arguments are given, only those paths are affected.*

Comment: that is the one I think, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clean -xdf` does it as the response by @0andriy says

Comment: Execute git clean -xdfn (for dry run) to first see what will be deleted